# Problemas com StyleBook Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, style

Olá. Estou tentando fazer a exibição de uma lista de produtos dentro de um listbox. Previamente uma query é carregada e pra cada item do pedido vou adicionando um item dentro do listbox. O fato é que precisei fazer uma alteração no style do item do listbox, o que após a edição e salvamento um stylebook é adicionado no form, em design mode as alterações são mostradas na tela, quando compilo o sistema ele sempre volta ao style default. Já fiz a edição do style defaul e do custom, tentei aplicar ambos em tempo de execução no onactive, oncreate e onshow do formulario. Fiz um teste criando um projeto novo e utilizando apenas um form e aplicando o mesmo conceito e funcionou. Mas quando aplico a mesma coisa no projeto que estou trabalhando não funciona. Não estou conseguindo aplicar o style no projeto.

> Alguém ja passou por esse problema, ou algo parecido?

O código que implementa a adição dos itens segue abaixo:

```
procedure TfrmVisualPed.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item:TListBoxItem;
begin
  inherited;
  if not DM.qryPedidosItens.IsEmpty then
  begin
    DM.qryPedidosItens.First;
    ListBox1.BeginUpdate;
    while not DM.qryPedidosItens.Eof do
    begin
      Item := TListBoxItem.Create(Nil);
      item.StyleLookup := 'listboxitembottomdetail';
      item.Width := 150;
      item.Height := 150;
      if FileExists('D:\TEMP\fotos\' + DM.qryPedidosItensCODIGO_PRODUTO.AsString + '.jpg') then
      begin
        Item.ItemData.Bitmap.LoadThumbnailFromFile('D:\TEMP\fotos\' + DM.qryPedidosItensCODIGO_PRODUTO.AsString + '.jpg',100,100);
      end else
      begin
        Item.ItemData.Bitmap := imgsemfoto.Bitmap;
      end;
      Item.ItemData.Text := DM.qryPedidosItensCODIGO_PRODUTO.AsString;
      item.Parent := ListBox1;
      item.OnClick := Nil;
      DM.qryPedidosItens.Next;
    end;
    ListBox1.EndUpdate;
    ListBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;
```

Segue algumas imagens:

[image: Design mode]
[image: Edição do style]
[image: Quando está em execução]

Comment: Tens a certeza que escolheste um style compativel com a plataforma? Há alguns só para android, outros so para windows, etc...

Comment: Na verdade não estou escolhendo, estou editando o custom e o default apenas para windows, e sempre os compilo para a mesma plataforma. E para cada plataforma deve-se fazer a mesma mudança nos estilos, senão não tem efeito tb.